# Crop base64 image data within a circle

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have an image which occupies complete screen. I have to save only the small portion of image, like content of 300px width and height from top 25%. I have attached an example which I found.

In the example, you can see a small circle on top of the image and in the next part, only the content inside the circle is shown. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

```css
.circular {
  width: 80vw;
  border-radius: 50%
}
```

```html
<img class="circular" src="https://i.imgur.com/VUychin.png">
```

You can use a base64 image on the `src` parameter, this is the same.

Comment: So the above changes, doesn't reduce the size of the image right?

Comment: Absolutely, this is just a "mask" the image isn't compressed or anything. This is just css